# Greek tag proposed changes

Tags: discussion

I would like to see a new [koine-greek](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/koine-greek) tag because there are also various dialects of classical Greek and later dialects of medieval and Byzantine Greek, not to mention modern Greek. We could make [greek](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greek) and [koine](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/koine) (a new tag) synonyms of [koine-greek](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/koine-greek).

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking it will be nice to have two short tag synonyms ([koine](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/koine) and [greek](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greek)), but properly speaking, [koine-greek](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/koine-greek) is more precise and should thus be the main tag.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking it's better to keep the tag short and use [greek](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greek), making the other two synonyms.

Answer (score -2):

I'm thinking it's better to keep the tag short and use [koine](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/koine), making the other two synonyms.